# Generating golang structs from protobufs without the extra hidden fields

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Consider the following message:

```
message Moo {
  uint64 generation = 1;
  string title = 2;
  bytes payload = 3;
  repeated string flags = 4;
}
```

In addition to the `type Moo struct` that protoc generates, which contains extra fields (`state`, `sizeCache`, `unknownFields` in the code I just generated), I also need to generate a type without the extra fields, something like

```
type MooLight struct {
    Generation uint64
    Title      string
    Payload    []byte
    Flags      []string
}
```

(whether the tags are there make no difference to me, I've omitted them here for clarity).

I know I can always write some code that takes the generated `moo.pb.go` file, and starting with `var File_moo_proto protoreflect.FileDescriptor` generate the "light" structs, but it would be better to let the protocol compiler do it. Any suggestions or advice? I tried looking at the go protoc plugin, and it's a tremendous amount of code.

Comment: What you want to achieve? Why additional fields bother you? `google.golang.org/protobuf/` internally uses these structures, so without them you cannot marshall/unmarshall these types, which makes them useless

Comment: You know how sometimes you have to do the wrong thing because you are not free to redesign things correctly and you have to work with a huge amount of existing code?

I have a service that had been defined with swagger; the generated code has `*Request` and `*Response` types that were generated from the swagger spec, but stuff has been heavily edited by hand. I got messages to generate the same go types as the existing code uses, but *its* marshalling would break when encountering the extra protobuf fields.

Comment: **Epiphany** :) It just occurred to me, though: I may be able to change the existing marshalling/unmarshalling code from the old swagger implementation to *ignore* these fields. Still, it would be useful to have an answer to the original question.